# extract a paragraph from a aeronautical text using python

Tags: python, regex

I am new in python and i try to extract a text from a paragraph using python.
the text is:

```
<stx>(FPL-ACF66-IN
-EH30/H-S/C
-LGKR0900
-N0100VFR KRK ARA
-LGTG0300
-DOF/120928)
<etx>
<stx>GG
(APL-ACF66-IN
-EH30/H-S/C
-LGKR0900
-N0100VFR KRK ARA
-LGTG0300
-DOF/110928)
<etx>
<stx>
(CNL-ACF66-IN
-EH30/H-S/C
-LGKR0900
-N0100VFR KRK ARA
-LGTG0300
-DOF/120928)<etx>
```

and i want to extract from FPL till -DOF/120928) the whole pagagraph

```
(FPL-ACF66-IN
-EH30/H-S/C
-LGKR0900
-N0100VFR KRK ARA
-LGTG0300
-DOF/120928)
```

i use that code but it extracts only the first line : FPL-ACF66-IN

```
import re

with open('FPL.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        works = f.read()

        pattern = 'FPL'+'.*'
        w =re.findall(pattern, works, re.I)
        for work in w:
            print(work)
```

what is my fault;

Comment: that you're matching everything after `FPL` using `.*`, you should restrict your match till your desired character/ word.

Comment: how should it be ;

Comment: see @Jan's answer

Answer (score 0):

While you surely can use regular expressions like ([**see a demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/I5WABP/1/), mind the modifiers)

```
\(FPL.+?-DOF/120928\)
```

this looks to me like some sort of `xml` file, so why don't you use a parser instead?

---

Snippet in `Python`:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'\(FPL.+?-DOF/120928\)', re.DOTALL)

with open("test.txt") as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    try:
        paragraph = rx.search(data).group(0)
    except:
        paragraph = None
    print(paragraph)
```

This yields

```
(FPL-ACF66-IN
-EH30/H-S/C
-LGKR0900
-N0100VFR KRK ARA
-LGTG0300
-DOF/120928)
```

---

If you want to have **all** paragraphs here, you could use

```
\([^()]+\)
```

Or even

```
<stx>(.+?)<etx>
```

And loop over them afterwards, see [**the modified demo**](https://regex101.com/r/I5WABP/2) and [**this one for `stx` and `etx`**](https://regex101.com/r/I5WABP/3).
For the latter:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'<stx>(.+?)<etx>', re.DOTALL)

with open("test.txt") as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    paragraphs = (m.group(1) for m in rx.finditer(data))

    for p in paragraphs:
        print(p)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like xml, because it misses the closing tags like `</stx>` and `</etx>`.  `<stx>` probably stands for 'start of text' and `<etx>` for 'end of text'.

Comment: @BioGeek: I guess so, have changed my answer to use `<stx>` and `<etx>`, respectively (in the end).